# I am unable to use svychisq() on categorical variables?

Tags: r, testing, survey, chi-squared

I am using svychisq() to compute the significance in the difference between proportions in my survey data but I keep getting an error that the approximation may be incorrect. My input and output are both categorical data.

```
obj <- svydesign(ids = ~1,
         strata = NULL,
         weights = survey_weights,
         data = survey_data)

svychisq(~input, ~output, obj)
```

Error message I am getting is "Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect". I am not sure why I am getting this error and am wondering if anybody knows why I might be getting this. Should I be doing a different test?

Comment: hi, does switching to `svychisq(~input+output, obj)`  solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I believe the way that the call to `svychisq()` is formulated in the question simply doesn't work. To run a test of independence/homogoneity of your input and output, you'd write what @AnthonyDamico put: `svychisq(~input+output, obj)`.